# python Timedelta overflow

Tags: python, python-2.7, integer-overflow, timedelta

I am trying to return a timedelta but when time_value is too large it overflows and gives an error. I can use a check to see if time_value is too large but I would prefer a wrapper that handles the error and returns a default. I have included the code for what I'm doing right now. Is there a version of timedelta or datetime that will do this for me?

```
def time_format(time_value):
            try:
                if time_value is None:
                    return 0
                elif time_value > 0:
                    return (timedelta(seconds=-time_value))
            except OverflowError:
                return 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`datetime.timedelta.min`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta.min) and [`datetime.timedelta.max`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta.max). Note that these two are not symmetric about 0.

Then your code becomes

```
time_offset = 0
if timedelta.min.total_seconds() <= -time_value <= timedelta.max.total_seconds():
    time_offset = timedelta(seconds=-time_value)
```